# Which flows are supported by the Oauth2 Module for Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

We'd like to add Oauth2 support for a spring mvc and spring security based web application, so the oauth2 security module (http://www.buynfctags.com/nfc-tags/stickers/printed-nfc-sticker-ntag.html) seems a great fit.

But which flows exactly are supported? The docs only list the web-server flwo, but what about client-side and resource owner password flow for example. Will it work out of the box?

Comment: Think you've made a typo in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the main OAuth2 flows are supported - authorization-code, implicit, client-credentials and password. There is more information in the [github wiki](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oauth2) and you might also want to take a look at the `authorization-server` element in the [namespace schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd).

The [CloudFoundry UAA project](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa) is a useful example of using Spring Security OAuth2 in practice.

Comment: thx. we have successfully implemented the spring oauth2 module by know and I've verified all flows.